# Log the time when raspberry pi connects to wifi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, wpa-supplicant

Is there a way to get the last time my raspberry pi connects to the wifi network defined in wpa_supplicant.conf?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to install an NTP client, and configure a script on the directories that have scripts to run after the interfaces go up.

You would want to execute a script after the interface goes up.

If In Debian do:

```
$sudo apt-get install ntpdate
```

The create the following script with vi

```
sudo vi /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
```

and place in the vi file the command:

```
ntpdate -b ntp_server_IP
```

then finish with:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
```

Please not the whilst there are other ntp clientes, the ntpdate choice is not accidental. ntpdate  -b permits to raise/bump the time on your system in one go without it having being done in small bumps.

Comment: Why the ntp client to get the date?

Comment: NTP is THE Internet-wide standard to keep equipments synced in time.

Comment: Yeah i know what ntp is. But i didn't understand how and where is the time of connection saved.

Comment: After the script you provided is being executed

Comment: ntpdate gets the time from a NTP server and sets the time with that data in a Unix server.

Comment: Sorry but how do i fetch that data?

Comment: write the "date" command on the command line

Comment: Doesn't date tells me the current time?

Comment: exactly. try "ntpdate -b 0.debian.pool.ntp.org" and the "date".

Comment: Couldn't i just put date >> ~/example_log.txt in that script?

Comment: you only what to log it, I understood now. I though you wanted to set it. Yes, it does.